# How does mmap(2) allocate and initialize memory?

Tags: c, linux, paging, mmap

Quoting from the man page for `mmap(2)`: "mmap() creates a new mapping in the virtual address space of the calling process.".

I wonder how the mapping is allocated and what exactly the return value points to.

If call `mmap(2)` on a valid file descriptor of a file which contains 10 characters plus an additional newline character and I pass 10 as the `length` argument to `mmap(2)`, then the memory I receive doesn't just contain the then characters I asked for, but the newline character, too. Also, `gdb` allows me to access the memory of the returned pointer at offsets much greater than 10. To be exact, the mapping was three 4096 byte pages long (max. offset was at 12287).

Why is more than one page allocated for this task and why is the mapping initialized with more bytes (`char`s) than I had asked for?
Also, what am I looking at when inspecting  any memory past the length of the mapping I requested?

Comment: If you allocate 10 bytes (with `malloc`, `mmap` or the older `sbrk`/`brk`, or any other system-specific allocation function), you should not go beyond that memory. That will lead to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Since memory mapping is likely done on a page-by-page basis, it’s not too surprising that you can see more data than you asked for.  That doesn’t necessarily mean you are allowed to access the “extra” memory though, as other implementations might not provide it.

Comment: @SupportUkraine I'm on version `6.3.6-200.fc38.x86_64` of the Linux kernel (Intel 11th gen).

Comment: "gdb allows me to access the memory" gdb is not a guardian of memory, it is a debugging tool. Whatever it allows you (the person behind the terminal) to do is above and beyond what a C program is allowed to do. The latter is fixed **in writing** by the relevant standard documents. "My program didn't crash and produced output I expected" is **not** the same thing as "my program is allowed to do what it does".